# DAO calling another DAO for nested objects

Tags: design-patterns, lazy-loading, dao

I'll explain it with an example. Assume, I've two tables:

```
Department(deptId, deptName)

Employee(empId, empName, deptId)
```

And a DAO for each of them. Employee has Many to One relationship to Department. In my domain model Employee refers Department object.

Now when I call finder on EmployeeDAO, should I make a call to DepartmentDAO from inside EmployeeDAO, to return a completely formed Employee Object(with Department). Below post suggests against it:

> [Can a DAO call DAO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988252/can-a-dao-call-dao)

**Note :** Domain objects are just for the sake of discussion, so please don't suggest to remodel them.

Comment: I assume the reason why you don't have answers to your question is that your second point ideally should be a new question alltogether.

Comment: @CKing removed second point for question to be more focussed.