# Calling one DAO from another DAOFactory

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, architecture

Currently, my application architecture flows like this:

> *View → Presenter → Some asynchronous executor → DAOFactory → DAO (interface) → DAO (Impl)*

For the time being, this kind of architecture works; mainly because I've only been needing one kind of DAO at the moment. But as the requirement grows, I'd need to expand to multiple DAOs, each with their own implementation on how to get the data.

Here's an illustration to my case:

[image]

The main headache comes from `FooCloudDao` which loads data from an API. This API needs some kind of authentication method - a string token that was stored during login (say, a `Session` object - yes, this too has its own DAO).

It's tempting to just pass a `Session` instance through `FooDaoFactory`, just in case there's no connection, but it seems hackish and counter-intuitive. The next thing I could imagine is to access `SessionDAOFactory` from within `FooDaoFactory` to gain instance of a `Session` (and then pass that when I need a `FooCloudDAO` instance).

But as I said, I'm not sure whether or not I could do a thing like this - well, may be I *could*, but is it this *really* the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I really like the way you explain your problem. That being said, is your question *is it ethical*? That doesn't seem like something within the scope of Stack Overflow because it makes the question become opinion based.

Comment: Well, I could just rephrase the question - *is it the correct way of doing this?* If that's also considered as opinion-based, I'm stuck. Then again, any answer must have a bit of the author's opinion in it.

Comment: Maybe this is better suited for programmmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I won't mind moving the question over to programmers.se should the majority think there's a need to do so. However, there's quite a few questions that are similar to this got asked and answered in SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285005/calling-one-dao-from-another-dao?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239354/advice-wanted-on-a-complex-structure-in-java-dao-and-service-layer-linking-coup?rq=1, to name a few.

Comment: As a Programmers.SE user, this seems like a good question for our site, so if any high-rep users here feel it's off-topic for SO then go ahead and vote for migration. Or just answer it here anyway, either is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your problem is actually that `FooCloudDao` has different "dependencies" than other components, and you want to avoid passing the dependencies through every class on the way.

Altough there are quite some design patterns which would kind of solve your problem, I would suggesting taking a look on ***Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control*** principles and frameworks. What you would do with this is:

> 1. You would create an **interface** for what your `FooCloudDao` needs, for example:

```
interface ApiTokenProvider {
     string GetToken();
 }
```

> 2. You would create and **implementation** of that interface which would get it from the session or wherever that thing comes from:

```
class SessionBasedApiTokenPrivider implements ApiTokenProvider {
    public string GetToken() {
        // get it from the session here
    }
}
```

> 3. The defined class above would need to be **registered with IoC container** of your choice as the implementation of `ApiTokenProvider`
>      interface (so that whoever asks for `ApiTokenProvider` will be decoupled
>      from the actual implementation -> the container would give him the
>      proper implementation).
> 4. You would have something called **constructor injection on your `FooCloudDao`** class (this is later used by the container to "inject"
>      your dependency):

```
public FooCloudDao(ApiTokenProvider tokenProvider) {
    // store the provider so that the class can use it later where needed
}
```

> 5. Your FooDaoFactory would use the **IoC container to resolve the `FooCloudDao`** with all its dependencies (so you would not
>      instantiate the `FooCloudDao` with `new`)

---

When following these steps you will make sure that:

- `FooDaoFactory` remains clean of passing dependecies through
- you make your code much more testable because you could test your `FooCloudDao`  without the real session (you could only give in the fake interface implementation)
- and all other benefits which come with Inversion of Control...

Note on the session: if you encounter the problem of getting the session in the `SessionBasedApiTokenProvider`, most of the time the session itself is also registered with the IoC controller, and injected where needed.

Comment: Nice solution! Actually, I've used DI before (Dagger) but decided to scrap it because of the boilerplate codes it tend to lead. But I guess it really *is* the way to go when talking about dependency optimization. Thanks for this insight!